# Cómo hacer join con MongoDB + Node JS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, join

estoy realizando un proyecto con MongoDB y Node JS; actualmente necesito realizar un JOIN de dos colecciones pero lo estoy pudiendo conseguir.

las colecciones son Categoría y Empresa:

```
var categoriaSchema = new Schema({
nombre: { type: String, required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario'] },
estado: { type: Boolean, default: true }});


var empresaSchema = new Schema({
nombre: { type: String, required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario'] },
estado: { type: Boolean, default: true },
categoria: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Categoria', required: [true, 'El id de la categoría es un campo obligatorio'] }});
```

cómo puedo realizar una búsqueda en nodejs para que cuando agregue una categoría, solamente me despliegue las empresas que poseen dicha categoría (ejemplo, restaurantes: todas las empresas con servicios de restaurantes).

Comment: que versión de mongo estas usando?

Comment: utilizo la v3.6.2 de MongoDB y la v8.9.1 de node

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar agregation ya que este mismo agrega un nuevo array donde se hará el emparte o comparación de los datos; que este caso se simulará la acción de llave primaria y llave foránea

La estructura genérica sería así

```
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: <colección a unir>,
        localField: <campo desde el documento de entrada>,
        foreignField: <campo de los documentos de la colección>,
        as: <campo de matriz de salida>
    }
}
```

### EJEMPLO

> usuarios [id, nombre, email]
>
> posts  [id, user_id, titulo, cuerpo]

Entonces el ejemplo en código de mongo debería quedar mas o menos así

```
db.usuarios.agregate({
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "posts",
            localField: "id",
            foreignField: "user_id",
            as: "mis_posts"
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alfredo, muchas gracias por la ayuda; luego de haber probado el ejemplo con mis colecciones en el Robo 3T, mi consulta es la siguiente: como filtras los resultados de búsqueda según un parametro de búsqueda?

por ejemplo, la colección Categoría que tengo, almacena tipos de servicios que ofrecen las empresas de turismo (agencias de viajes, hoteles, empresas de buses, etc).

Lo que deseo es poder filtrar las empresas de acuerdo a la categoría que se le asigno; quedando de la siguiente manera:

1. Agencias de viajes: 13 empresas (nombre, estado, etc).
2. Hoteles: 15 empresas (nombre, estado, etc).

y así sucesivamente.